# Facebook button changes position when clicked

Tags: css, facebook, button, zurb-foundation

I have the following problem with the like&share facebook button. When I click on 'share' everything works as expected, but when I click on like, the pop-up box is cut and the whole div object is moved to the left. How can I overcome this?
Here are pictures:

http://collabl.bingo.icnhost.net/resources/pr2.png
http://collabl.bingo.icnhost.net/resources/pr3.png

The code I use is:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="250" style="height:20px;"      layout="button_count"></div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js', function(){
FB.init({
  appId: '.......',
  channelUrl: '//.......',
  status     : false,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
  xfbml      : true  
});
$('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks nothing like what I'm using for the javascript.

Try using the code generated directly from the facebook developers page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/